# Deploy Apple iOS Swift App to iPhone with Free Apple ID

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes

I am using a commercial Mac VM Service over the Internet. Is it possible to deploy a simple HelloWorld app to my iPhone without paying for a 99 dollar developer account? I cannot tether. On the VM I am using Xcode and Swift. The commercial provider says to get a free Apple developer account and then use iTunes iConnect. I have an Apple ID, however I cannot find a way to make it a free developer account. If the answer is NO and I must buy a 99 dollar account, please end my searching and just let me know.

Comment: You need to connect your iPhone to the computer running Xcode, so unless you can figure out a way to connect it remotely using some 3rd party software (maybe [*this*](https://www.eltima.com/wiki/user-guides/usb-mac/rdp-usb-mac.html)?), then you're probably out of luck. Even if you pay for the account, debugging would be difficult if not impossible.

Comment: Testing this approach tonight.  Thank-you for the link.

Comment: Unfortunately the USB Gateway is $159.95.  Cheaper to get the $99 Apple Dev Account.  I do consider your comment as "No", it is not possible to deploy an app to an iphone without paying for a dev account or having a real Mac.  Coder256, I will accept your comment as answer if you would please post as answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend buying a developer account even if there is no other way. Even once you've paid for your developer account, Apple has lots of stupid rules about what kinds of apps you're not allowed to publish: no ad blockers that block in-app ads, no browsers that use other web engines than Safari's... These are just examples, so even if your app isn't one of those, if I were you I would just give up and make a web application that can be accessed through a browser instead. If you can find a free way to publish your app that's great, but otherwise *don't pay $99 just to mess with Apple*.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to connect the phone (through USB or possibly Wi-Fi) to the computer that is running Xcode. Unless you have physical access to that computer, this would be difficult.

However, something that *might* work is VirtualHere's [USB server](https://virtualhere.com/windows_server_software)/[client](https://virtualhere.com/usb_client_software) (free for 1 device, the phone) along with [LogMeIn's Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net) (free for 5 devices, you would use 1 for the server and 1 for the client). Another solution that I had mentioned was [Eltima's USB Network Gate](https://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-network-mac/), although that is $159.95.

One last thing to note is that even if you buy an Apple Developer Account, you still may not be able to install your apps remotely on a device (maybe TestFlight would work), and even if you could install them, it would be difficult or impossible to use live debugging. However, this would not be an issue wither either of the solutions in the previous paragraph.